# How to use pymc to parameterize a probabilistic graphical model?

Tags: pymc3, pymc, bayesian-networks, probabilistic-programming

How can one use pymc to parameterize a probabilistic graphical model?

Suppose I have a PGM with two nodes `X` and `Y`.
Lets say `X->Y` is the graph.

And `X` takes two values `{0,1}`, and
`Y` also takes two values `{0,1}`.

I want to use pymc to learn the parameters of the distribution and populate the
graphical model with it for running inferences.

The way I could think of is as follows:

```
X_p = pm.Uniform("X_p", 0, 1)
X = pm.Bernoulli("X", X_p, values=X_Vals, observed=True)
Y0_p = pm.Uniform("Y0_p", 0, 1)
Y0 = pm.Bernoulli("Y0", Y0_p, values=Y0Vals, observed=True)
Y1_p = pm.Uniform("Y1_p", 0, 1)
Y1 = pm.Bernoulli("Y1", Y1_p, values=Y1Vals, observed=True)
```

Here `Y0Vals` are values of `Y` corresponding to `X` values = 0
And `Y1Vals` are values of `Y` corresponding to `X` values = 1.

The plan is to draw MCMC samples from these and use the means of `Y0_p` and `Y1_p`
to populate the discrete bayesian network's probability...  So the probability table
for `P(X) = (X_p,1-X_p)` while that of `P(Y/X)`:

```
  Y  0       1
X 
0   Y0_p   1-Y0_p
1   Y1_p   1-Y1_p
```

Questions:

1. Is this the correct way of doing this?
2. Does not this get clumsy, especially if I have `X` having 100s of discrete values?
   or if a variable has two parents `X` and `Y` with 10 discrete values each?
3. Is there something better I can do?
4. Are there any good books that detail how we can do this kind of interconnection.

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I am in a similar situation, have you seen any new improvements in pymc3 that can do this?